# SQL LEFT JOIN using alias name

Tags: oracle

Just started working on Oracle SQL and trying to use left join. Getting following error, plz help.

```
select usr_grpid as "usr_role_role_id" 
from users 
left join user_role on users.usr_role_role_id = user_role.usr_role_role_id;
```

Error Message:

> ORA-00904: "USERS"."USR_ROLE_ROLE_ID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Actually column name of first table is different then second table though the data is same.

Comment: Don't use the alias for the column in the join, use the actual column name instead.

Comment: In addition to what the others have said, it's a bit pointless doing an outer join if you're only selecting the join column. Hopefully that's just an example to demonstrate your issue, and your real query has more columns in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select usr_grpid as "usr_role_role_id" 
from `users` 
left join user_role on `users`.usr_role_role_id = user_role.usr_role_role_id;
```

or

```
select usr_grpid as "usr_role_role_id" 
from users usr
left join user_role on usr.usr_role_role_id = user_role.usr_role_role_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
select users.usr_grpid
from users 
left join user_role on users.usr_grpid = user_role.usr_grpid;
```

Note:
 Please don't use the alias for the column in the join, use the actual column name instead.

Answer (score -1):

Besides not using allian is join condition, as the both tables are using same column to join, you may also use a [NATURAL LEFT JOIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljnaturaljoin.html)

```
SELECT usr_grpid
FROM users 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN user_role;
```

but it would be helpful to have allias for each table to specify from which table to get the value.

something like this:

```
SELECT a.usr_grpid
FROM users a
NATURAL LEFT JOIN user_role b;
```

Comment: I would advise against using a natural join, since it means that if a column was added to one of the tables that shared a name with one of the columns in the other table, your join condition would change. Plus it makes the query harder to understand without knowing the structure of the tables off the top of your head.